# jQuery opacity animation aliasing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, opacity, antialiasing

I am trying to animate a text opacity with jQuery animate. I've noticed that when opacity value is set to 1, a bad anti-aliasing effect appears after animation in Chrome (version 35.0.1916.153): see image below.

[image: Opacity antialiasing effect in Chrome]

```
$('#good').animate({
    opacity:'0.99'
}, 2000);

$('#bad').animate({
    opacity:'1'
}, 2000);
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KzNc8/)**

I've tested it in Safari (version 5.1.7), Firefox (version 18.0.1) and it works well. I've tried to add the font smoothing filter suggested [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402698/webkit-opacity-transition-issues-with-text) but it doesn't seem to work. Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/38Uvr/) with div

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#good').animate({opacity: 0.4}, 2000, false, null);
    $('#bad').animate({opacity: 1}, 2000, false, null);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/38Uvr/1/) with `<p>`

Your mistake is you dont use [ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

I recomended use css animation without JS
[CSS ANIMATION JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/38Uvr/2/)

```
.pick-opacity_1 {
    -webkit-animation: opacity_1 2s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity_1 {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.pick-opacity_2 {
    -webkit-animation: opacity_2 5s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity_2 {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }

    75% {
        opacity: 0.6;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

UPDATED:
[TEST 0.99 JSFIDDLE ANIMATION OPACITY](http://jsfiddle.net/38Uvr/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to set opacity to 1 (and this is the value where the issue happens).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, I've added an image to OP to clarify the issue. Even using document ready (and setting `#good` opacity to 0.99 to make a comparison), the effect is the same.

Comment: @Giorgio, my link with jsFIddle is work on your laptop?

Comment: Mikail, your last fiddle works because you set opacity to 0.99, not 1. If 0.99 (which was my initial workaround) works, I'll use it. But the goal of my question was: is opacity:1 a known bug for Chrome?

Comment: @Giorgio, my chrome work fine with opacity to 1 animation.(35.0.1916.153 m)

Comment: Mikail, I trust you, even if I still see the problem. So maybe it's not a browser problem (and actually now I don't have any clue of what it may be). +1 for your help.