# CSS Font Color Changes When Opacity Changes in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, fonts, colors

I've noticed that when updating the opacity of text that the color changes.  This only happens in Chrome (current version 58, June 1, 2017).

Attached is an image comparing the same text with the same color but differences in opacity.  The first line is assigned `opacity: 1.0;` and the second line is assigned `opacity: 0.99;`.  Additionally, it appears that the weight has also slightly increased, but I suspect that has more to do with how the colors are used for anti-aliasing.

[image]

Is this a bug in the Chrome Browser?

The font used is:  **[Muli Semibold (weight 600)](https://fonts.google.com/selection?selection.family=Muli:600)** with an assigned color of  **#45B4E4**.

---

**[EDIT]**

Here are versions in yellow (**#E2E445**), red (**#E44545**) and green (**#45E445**).  As you can see, it's not only blue that makes this problem obvious.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webkit Opacity Transition Issues with Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402698/webkit-opacity-transition-issues-with-text)

Comment: This behaviour has been present in chrome for quite a while..

Comment: I evaluated the pixel width of the characters and found them to be identical (eg: the 1 in 1.0 is 5 pixels across). I determined the beginning of each character was where the pixel value dipped below #ffffff. Humans have really good vision in the blue part of the spectrum. $5 says you wouldn't see the issue if it was yellow. :)

Comment: We can see the issue in yellow and all other colors.

Comment: @James setting `-webkit-font-smoothing` doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Yep I agree it's messed up, [here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cg32z46g/).  It looks like it's ok with a dark background.

Comment: I can still see the difference clearly with a dark background.  I'm surprised that `-webkit-font-smoothing` doesn't do anything since it's clearly an issue with the visual edges of the text.  In darker colors (`opacity: 1;`)the antialiasing is grayscale while in brighter colors (`opacity: 0.99;`) the font edges are the same color as the text, which not only causes it to appear brighter but also lends to it's heavier font weight.